# Asimov end of the world short story

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov

I looking for the name of one of Asimov's short stories, where the world ends and all dead people start coming out of their graves and start talking to their relatives.

I know some kind of celestial herald or angel is involved, but I don't remember much more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*[The Last Trump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Trump)*, from the *Earth Is Room Enough* anthology.